# What are the dimensions for the Facebook Timeline cover photo?

Tags: facebook

I've googled a resolution of height: 851px and width: 315px  but it actually seems to be considerably larger than this.

[image: Cover Photo]

The full image https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJAdn.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Facebook help](https://www.facebook.com/help/125379114252045) it is indeed 851 × 315 (in pixels). The minimum size you can upload is 399 × 150 (but then it'll be stretched to fit).

> Cover photos are 851 pixels wide and 315 pixels tall. If you upload an image that's smaller than these dimensions, it will be stretched to this larger size. The image you upload must be at least 399 pixels wide and 150 pixels tall.
>
> To get the fastest load times for your Page, upload an sRGB JPG file that's 851 pixels wide, 315 pixels tall and less than 100 kilobytes. For images with your logo or text, you may get a higher quality result by using a PNG file.

Answer (score 3):

Using [MeasureIt](http://frayd.us/), that appears to be accurate.

[image: Measure of Cover Photo]

Your image seems to be enlarged

[image: Profile Photo]

[image: Enlarged Photo]

Comment: This is how big it actually looks: http://i.imgur.com/JZ1yp.jpg

Comment: Ahh, finally realized that Chrome was zooming in a bit for Facebook pages. I had it set to 120% too make Japanese easier to read. This is why when I tried using MeasureIt myself, it was giving me nonsense resolutions (reporting a 1600px wide screen, even though my resolution is 1920x1080).

Answer (score 0):

The default image size required for the facebook time cover by default is 850 x 315 pixels, a larger image will also work. The image less then 720 pixel wide will not be accepted.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Please be careful when posting links as self promotion can be regarded as spam here. You should avoid just posting links in answers. Instead, post all relevant and helpful content in the answer and if it is required post a link for reference. I would suggest you read the [FAQ] before posting further, in particular the [section regarding self promotion](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).